# Click in checkbox gives me undefined

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, checkbox, datatable

I am new in php and I have problem whith checkbox. Infact when I check one of the checkboxs in table it should gives me my data but unfortunately it gives me undefined.

here is my code befor click in checkbox
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tsuOY.jpg)

and after click for exemple in the checkbox in the first line
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/muoTh.jpg)

and this is my code :

```
$(document).on('click', '.check_box', function(){
    var html = '';
    if(this.checked)
    {
        html = '<td><input type="checkbox" id="'+$(this).attr('id')+'" data-Projet="'+$(this).data('Libelle_Projet')+'" data-Num-Produit="'+$(this).data('Num_Produit')+'" data-Libelle-Produit="'+$(this).data('Libelle_Produit')+'" data-Titre-Foncier-Produit="'+$(this).data('Titre_Foncier_Produit')+'" data-Superficie-Produit="'+$(this).data('Superficie_Produit')+'" data-Date-Reception-Administratif-Temp="'+$(this).data('Date_Reception_Administratif_Temp')+'" data-Date-Contrat-Temp="'+$(this).data('Date_Contrat_Temp')+'" class="check_box" checked /></td>';
        html += '<td>'+$(this).data("Libelle_Projet")+'</td>';
        html += '<td>'+$(this).data("Num_Produit")+'</td>';
        html += '<td>'+$(this).data("Libelle_Produit")+'</td>';
        html += '<td>'+$(this).data("Titre_Foncier_Produit")+'</td>';
        html += '<td>'+$(this).data("Superficie_Produit")+'</td>';
        html += '<td><input type="date" name="Date_Reception_Administratif_Temp[]" class="form-control" value="'+$(this).data("Date_Reception_Administratif_Temp")+'" /></td>';
        html += '<td><input type="date" name="Date_Contrat_Temp[]" class="form-control" value="'+$(this).data("Date_Contrat_Temp")+'" /><input type="hidden" name="hidden_id[]" value="'+$(this).attr('id')+'" /></td>';
    }
    else
    {
        html = '<td><input type="checkbox" id="'+$(this).attr('id')+'" data-Projet="'+$(this).data('Libelle_Projet')+'" data-Num-Produit="'+$(this).data('Num_Produit')+'" data-Libelle-Produit="'+$(this).data('Libelle_Produit')+'" data-Titre-Foncier-Produit="'+$(this).data('Titre_Foncier_Produit')+'" data-Superficie-Produit="'+$(this).data('Superficie_Produit')+'" data-Date-Reception-Administratif-Temp="'+$(this).data('Date_Reception_Administratif_Temp')+'" data-Date-Contrat-Temp="'+$(this).data('Date_Contrat_Temp')+'" class="check_box" /></td>';
        html += '<td>'+$(this).data('Libelle_Projet')+'</td>';
        html += '<td>'+$(this).data('Num_Produit')+'</td>';
        html += '<td>'+$(this).data('Libelle_Produit')+'</td>';
        html += '<td>'+$(this).data('Titre_Foncier_Produit')+'</td>';
        html += '<td>'+$(this).data('Superficie_Produit')+'</td>';
        html += '<td>'+$(this).data('Date_Reception_Administratif_Temp')+'</td>';    
        html += '<td>'+$(this).data('Date_Contrat_Temp')+'</td>';         
    }
    $(this).closest('tr').html(html);
});
```

my table code :

```
<form method="post" id="update_form">
        <div id="divShow" class="table-responsive">
          <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
            <thead>
              <th width="2%"></th>
              <th width="15%">Projet</th>
              <th width="10%">Numéro Produit</th>
              <th width="15%">Dénomination</th>
              <th width="10%">Titre Foncier</th>
              <th width="5%">Superficie</th>
              <th width="15%">Date Réception Admin</th>
              <th width="15%">Date Contrat</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody></tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        
        <br />

        <div align="left">
          <input type="submit" name="multiple_update" id="multiple_update" class="btn btn-info" value="Valider"  style="display: none;" />
        </div>

        <br />

        <div id="msgSelectProduit" style="display: none;"></div>
        <div id="msgSelectDateContrat" style="display: none;"></div>
      </form>

$.ajax({
        url:"selectTOUT.php",
        method:"POST",
        dataType:"json",
        success:function(data)
        {
            var html = '';
            for(var count = 0; count < data.length; count++)
            {
                html += '<tr>';
                html += '<td><input type="checkbox" id="'+data[count].id+'" data-Projet="'+data[count].Libelle_Projet+'" data-Num-Produit="'+data[count].Num_Produit+'" data-Libelle-Produit="'+data[count].Libelle_Produit+'" data-Titre-Foncier-Produit="'+data[count].Titre_Foncier_Produit+'" data-Superficie-Produit="'+data[count].Superficie_Produit+'" data-Date-Reception-Administratif-Temp="'+data[count].Date_Reception_Administratif_Temp+'" data-Date-Contrat-Temp="'+data[count].Date_Contrat_Temp+'" class="check_box"/></td>';
                html += '<td>'+data[count].Libelle_Projet+'</td>';
                html += '<td>'+data[count].Num_Produit+'</td>';
                html += '<td>'+data[count].Libelle_Produit+'</td>';
                html += '<td>'+data[count].Titre_Foncier_Produit+'</td>';
                html += '<td>'+data[count].Superficie_Produit+'</td>';
                html += '<td>'+data[count].Date_Reception_Administratif_Temp+'</td>';
                html += '<td>'+data[count].Date_Contrat_Temp+'</td></tr>';
            }
            $('tbody').html(html);
        }
    });
```

Comment: can you give me html code of checkbox

Comment: Is it possible for you to post the markdown (the HTML) code. There is something a bit off, about the whole this. You're listening on the class `.check_box` - but then you're getting the id (`$(this).attr('id')` from _the clicked object_ . But that is the checkbox (and no the row). So either your HTML is quite wierdly written - or that could be the explanation, why it doesn't work.

Comment: @mahmoudmagdy yes sure I add it in the post and thank you in advance

Comment: @Zeth thank you for your help yes I didn't know where the problem I follow a tutorial but it doesn't work for me I add the code of my table in the post

Comment: where is your datatable html code ?

Comment: there something is vague

Comment: @mahmoudmagdy oh sorry I add it it's a function that I called

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**try to convert some dash to underscode in your
like that data-aa-b to data-aa_b**

i think this is the problem

Comment: try to make dash after data directly and others become underscore

Comment: Thank you so much sir, yes the problem is with the dashs